# Apache can't find directory even though it is installed in the correct location

Tags: apache

I have tried installing Apache by itself and in a XAMPP package. I  get this error in Windows cmd panel:

> Syntax error on line 39 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: ServerRoot must be a valid directory

Or in XAMPP:

> 09:58:10  [Apache]    Apache Service detected with wrong path
> 09:58:10  [Apache]    Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
> 09:58:10  [Apache]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
> 09:58:10  [Apache]    Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
> 09:58:10  [Apache]    Expected Path: "d:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice`

I am an absolute beginner, could it be that I need to adjust settings in order to allow Apache access to the files? To me the path seems to be correct, uninstalling and reinstalling hasn't helped.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is on line 39 of `C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf`?

Comment: The error is very clear: *ServerRoot must be a valid directory*.  It even tells you the line number to find the problem.  So what do you have for `ServerRoot`?

Answer (score 0):

apache defaul root is  /usr/local/etc/httpd
and www/html/ for public requests on the server. If you are using XAAMP to setup a local server for further browser requests your project files must be at C:\wamp64\www and you can acess the on any browser you are using at 127.0.0.1/